# Deleting a value in a hash table using chaining

Tags: c++, arrays, hash

I have a function which searches for a value in a hash table:

```
bool search(int n, Node* hashtable[]) {
    int x = n % 10;
    Node * temp;
    for (temp = hashtable[x]; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next) {
        if (temp->value == n) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

How can I make a function which deletes a value in `hashtable`?
I'm guessing that I have to change the `return true;` part to something that says:
"ok, delete that value, but what about the other values in that linked list?"

For example, I had `112 -> 1112 -> 111112` and I wanted to delete `1112`.

Answer (score 2):

To delete something in a singly-linked list, you have to get the link to it to point to either the next element or `NULL` (if deleting the last element).  When deleting a list with only one entry, you need to change `hashtable[n]` to `NULL`.  But, we can't tell if this list is singly- or doubly-linked.  If Node has a `prev` pointer too, you'll also need to correct it in a similar way.  My suggestion is to write out the cases you need to handle on paper and think through the way the pointers should be moved.

CASE 1

```
hashtable[n] -> Node-to-delete -> NULL
```

CASE 2

```
hashtable[n] -> Node -> Node-to-delete -> NULL
```

CASE 3

```
hashtable[n] -> Node-to-delete -> Node -> NULL
```

CASE 4

```
hashtable[n] -> Node -> Node-to-delete -> Node -> NULL
```

> I'm guessing I have to change the return true; part to something that says: "ok, delete that value, but what about the other values in that linked list?"

If the calling code asks to delete a value in a list, it may or may not want to verify that the element was found.  If you want to give the caller that insight, then you can still return true or false.  It may be better to use an enum to make the import of the returned value unambiguous:

```
enum Result { Element_Found_And_Deleted, Element_Not_Found };

Result delete(int n, Node* hashtable[]);

// client usage:
if (delete(4, my_hashtable) != Element_Found_And_Deleted)
    FATAL("element not found - code must be broken");
...if applicable, or perhaps...
if (delete(4, my_hashtable) != Element_Found_And_Deleted)
    std::cout << "hey, you haven't added that value yet\n";
```

For `search`, if the Node contained anything more than the `value` key, then the caller may have wanted to access it and returning a pointer to the data would have been more useful than a boolean indicator of whether the node was found.